# Is I2C communication using two different IDEs possible?

Tags: arduino, ide, i2c

I have an Atmel AVR as I2C master and an Arduino as slave. The AVR is programmed in Atmel Studio and the Arduino in Arduino IDE. Is this communication possible? If not, how can it be performed? My problem is that the Atmel controllers for I2C transaction use a format to read/write commands. But I can't find any special commands in  Arduino. How can I perform this?

```
typedef struct {
  /* ! TWI chip address to communicate with. */
  char chip;
  /* ! TWI address/commands to issue to the other chip (node). */
  uint8_t addr[3];
  /* ! Length of the TWI data address segment (1-3 bytes). */
  int addr_length;
  /* ! Where to find the data to be written. */
  uint8_t *buffer;
  /* ! How many bytes do we want to write. */
  unsigned int length;
} twi_package_t;
```

This code is the parameter to pass in the I2C master, that is AVR. My problem is with the second parameter. Any ideas what should I do here?

Thanks.

Comment: and IDE is just a fancy text editor with a few convenient tools to create software. it does not matter what IDE you use. your arduino is nothing but an atmel avr... did it cross your mind that you could simply google "arduino i2c" if you want to know how i2c is done in the Arduino world?

Answer (score 1):

I2C is a standard protocol that doesn't rely on an IDE. The Arduino IDE has a software layer that hides stuff from the (casual) user, enabling them to achieve things like, indeed, I2C communication. As long as your code is correct on both machines, there is absolutely no issue.

Comment: thanks for the clarification,I have added my code part,if its possible can you giv me an idea about it?